# How do you disconnect an object from it's hibernate session in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to do this, but I get the error.

"a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"

It looks like I need to remove dbObject from the hibernate session.

```
def object = messageParserService.parseMessage(messageType, messageText)
def dbObject = object.getClass().findByIdentifier(object.identifier)
if(dbObject != null){
    object.id = dbObject.id
    object.dateCreated = dbObject.dateCreated
}
if(!object.save()) {
    object.errors.each {println it}
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

dbObject.discard() did the trick.

```
def object = messageParserService.parseMessage(messageType, messageText)
def dbObject = object.getClass().findByIdentifier(object.identifier)
if(dbObject != null){
    object.id = dbObject.id
    object.dateCreated = dbObject.dateCreated
    dbObject.discard()
}
if(!object.save()) {
    object.errors.each {println it}
}
```

See the [GORM discard() documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/discard.html).