# can GORM duplicate whole object?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

we are using grails to develop some web application
For Domain class that have child class , I'm wondering if we can duplicate whole object including all child object that belong to Parent ?

Thank you

Comment: why would you need it? do you need to duplicate the objects in session or in the db?

Comment: This answer might help you: [proper-implementation-of-clone-for-domain-classes-to-duplicate-a-grails-domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220711/proper-implementation-of-clone-for-domain-classes-to-duplicate-a-grails-domain)

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing. The oldschool approach is to navigate your hierarchy, `setId(null)` and hope for the best.  You may have a chance to a generic solution in your case using gorm meta informations.

Comment: @PhilMr clone copy only object itself ? , I need to create all child object too

Answer (score 1):

As given in the comments, you can extend gorm with a `clone` method.

However, a very simple solution if you don't want to mess with the gorm api is to detach the existing object and just "resave" it. Note that this won't perform a `deepClone`.

Steps:

1. Null the id.
2. Update fields that should differ in the copy.
3. Detach the object in question.
4. Save it.

Code example, assuming a domain class `Region` which has a unique `name` property that needs to change before saving:

```
def copyRegion(Region region, String newName) {
    region.id = null
    region.name = newName
    region.discard()
    if (region.save()) {
        // handle success
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290259/how-do-you-disconnect-an-object-from-its-hibernate-session-in-grails) about disconnecting an object.

Comment: clone copy only object itself ? , I need to create all child object too